# How can I modify a bibliography style to include annotations with xpatch?

Tags: biblatex, annotations, xpatch

I need to create an annotated bibliography using the `biblatex-sbl` package. I have managed to hack something together by creating a custom `bbx` file, but I was introduced to `xpatch` as a possible, more elegant solution. After scanning the docs and reading a bit, I have not been able to find a solution of my own. The following is a sample of a working tex file:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,oneside,openany]{book}

\usepackage{sbl-paper}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{selectedworks.bib}
@article{Sasson:1966aa,
    Author = {Sasson, Jack M.},
    Date-Added = {2017-10-27 23:26:58 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2017-11-14 01:28:31 +0000},
    Issn = {0021-9231},
    Journaltitle = {Journal of Biblical Literature},
    Number = {4},
    Pages = {473-476},
    Title = {Circumcision in the Ancient Near East},
    Volume = {85},
    Year = {1966},
    Annote = {Annotation text.}}

@article{Polaski:1998aa,
    Author = {Polaski, Donald C.},
    Date-Added = {2017-10-27 23:24:22 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2017-10-27 23:26:44 +0000},
    Issn = {03090892},
    Journaltitle = {Journal for the Study of the Old Testament},
    Number = {77},
    Pages = {55-73},
    Title = {Reflections on a Mosaic Covenant: The Eternal Covenant (Isaiah 24:5) and Intertextuality},
    Year = {1998},
    Annote = {Annotation text.}}

@article{Mor:2012aa,
    Author = {Mor, Menahem},
    Date-Added = {2017-10-27 23:19:43 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2017-10-27 23:23:18 +0000},
    Issn = {12242284},
    Pages = {161-193},
    Title = {Are There Any New Factors Concering the Bar Kokhba Revolt?},
    Volume = {18},
    Year = {2012},
    Annote = {Annotation text.}}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{selectedworks.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{Sasson:1966aa}
\nocite{Mor:2012aa}
\nocite{Polaski:1998aa}

\printbibliography[title=Annotated Bibliography]
\end{document}
```

The following is defined in the `sbl.bbx`:

```
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{inissuetitle}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{version}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{organization}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{shortjournal+issue}%
  \usebibmacro{pages}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{addendum}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{issn}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit
  \ifboolexpr{
    togl {relatedseen}
    or
    not togl {bbx:related}
  }
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}%
}
```

I want to add something like the following in order to incorporate the annotations:

```
  \par
  \usebibmacro{annotation}
  \newunit\newblock
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use:

```
\xpatchbibdriver{article}{%
    \usebibmacro{finentry}%
    }{%
    \setunit\par
    \usebibmacro{annotation}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{finentry}%
    }{}{}
```

[image]

According to xpatch's documentation, the sintax of `xpatchbibdriver` is:

```
\xpatchbibdriver{<name>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
```

So there we are searching for `\usebibmacro{finentry}%` in the bibdriver for `article` and replacing it with the added content of interest.

Or in full:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,oneside,openany]{book}

\usepackage{sbl-paper}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\begin{filecontents}{selectedworks.bib}
@article{Sasson:1966aa,
    Author = {Sasson, Jack M.},
    Date-Added = {2017-10-27 23:26:58 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2017-11-14 01:28:31 +0000},
    Issn = {0021-9231},
    Journaltitle = {Journal of Biblical Literature},
    Number = {4},
    Pages = {473-476},
    Title = {Circumcision in the Ancient Near East},
    Volume = {85},
    Year = {1966},
    Annote = {Annotation text.}}

@article{Polaski:1998aa,
    Author = {Polaski, Donald C.},
    Date-Added = {2017-10-27 23:24:22 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2017-10-27 23:26:44 +0000},
    Issn = {03090892},
    Journaltitle = {Journal for the Study of the Old Testament},
    Number = {77},
    Pages = {55-73},
    Title = {Reflections on a Mosaic Covenant: The Eternal Covenant (Isaiah 24:5) and Intertextuality},
    Year = {1998},
    Annote = {Annotation text.}}

@article{Mor:2012aa,
    Author = {Mor, Menahem},
    Date-Added = {2017-10-27 23:19:43 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2017-10-27 23:23:18 +0000},
    Issn = {12242284},
    Pages = {161-193},
    Title = {Are There Any New Factors Concering the Bar Kokhba Revolt?},
    Volume = {18},
    Year = {2012},
    Annote = {Annotation text.}}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{selectedworks.bib}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{inissuetitle}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{version}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{organization}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{shortjournal+issue}%
  \usebibmacro{pages}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{addendum}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{issn}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit
  \ifboolexpr{
    togl {relatedseen}
    or
    not togl {bbx:related}
  }
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}%
}


\xpatchbibdriver{article}{%
    \usebibmacro{finentry}%
    }{%
    \setunit\par
    \usebibmacro{annotation}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{finentry}%
    }{}{}


\begin{document}

\nocite{Sasson:1966aa}
\nocite{Mor:2012aa}
\nocite{Polaski:1998aa}

\printbibliography[title=Annotated Bibliography]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Brilliant! That worked perfectly. Thank you, so much. Not sure how I missed the syntax on `\xpatchbibdriver`, but it makes sense now.

Comment: What do you mean the code isn't compilable? It compiles OK for me using the current version of `biblatex-sbl`  (2017/01/15 v0.8.1) and v3.8 of `biblatex`. (I'm the author of `biblatex-sbl` so if there's a problem, I'd like to fix it.)

Comment: You don't need the `DelcareBibliographyDriver{article}{...}` lines BTW. Your patch works fine without it.

Comment: @DavidPurton, it didn't work for me here (updated TL 2017). The use of `sbl-paper` threw me the error `Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).` on line 6 of `biblatex-sdf.def`. Perhaps I'm missing something, but I thought I could still provide a meaningful answer and thus provided it using the OP's `DeclareBibliographyDriver`, which I assumed belonged to his custom `bbx` file, but lacked several of its macros. I'm I doing something wrong in loading of the package (or perhaps in compilation)? If, given this comment, you feel the answer should indeed be corrected or improved, I'll be glad to try.

Comment: Ah! Helpful, thanks. I think I know why this is happening. You are running `biblatex` 3.8a I'm guessing. I used a bad hack to check for the `biblatex` version which assumes a number as version. I had better fix this. Thanks!

Comment: And, true, the `DelcareBibliographyDriver{article}{...}` is not really needed, but it does help to understand what is going on with the `xpatch` for all those not really familiar with the bibliography drivers, which are those who might find this answer useful.

Comment: @DavidPurton, that might be it. I can't do it from here then, but if you'd like to edit the answer for the situation of a normally running `biblatex-sbl` please be my guest. I wouldn't be troubled at all, on the contrary.

Comment: yup! From the logs here `biblatex 2017/11/05 v3.8a`

Comment: For the sake of completeness `biblatex-sbl` 0.8.2 is now in CTAN, TeXLive, and MikTeX, and will now not give errors with `biblatex` 3.8a.

Comment: @DavidPurton, answer duly updated too.