# How to make an annotated bibliography using biblatex

Tags: biblatex, annotations

[The documentation](https://mirror.math.princeton.edu/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf#subsubsection.2.2.2)
specifies the `annotation` field and even goes so far as to mention it's
use in annotated bibliographies:

> annotation field (literal)
> This field may be useful when implementing a style for annotated bibliographies...

The problem is, I do not know how to invoke the annotated bibliography
"style" using `biblatex`.

[Without biblatex it seems you could use
`\bibliographystyle{annotate}`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/100596/214194),
but trying to use it with `biblatex` throws "\bibliographystyle invalid".

I want to achieve the same thing as [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/100596/214194), but with `biblatex`, ideally leveraging it's `annotation` field.

What I have in my `.bib` is:

```
@misc{kyber,
    author       = {Leon Botros and Matthias J. Kannwischer and Peter Schwabe},
    title        = {Memory-Efficient High-Speed Implementation of Kyber on Cortex-M4},
    howpublished = {Cryptology ePrint Archive, Report 2019/489},
    year         = {2019},
    note         = {\url{https://ia.cr/2019/489}},
    annotation   = {Crystals-Kyber PQC spec (one of the NIST PQC finalists).}
}
```

Comment: Use `bibstyle=reading`.

Comment: Ah, very nice! And led me to [the right section in the documentation](https://mirror.math.princeton.edu/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf#subsubsection.3.3.2). Go ahead and put this as an answer. If no one has anything better, I'll accept.

Comment: Note that `biblatex` has a dedicated field for URLs called `url`. So instead of `note = {\url{https://ia.cr/2019/489}},` you can say `url = {https://ia.cr/2019/489},`.

Comment: If you don't want to use `style=reading`, you can use the method shown in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/442062/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/560417/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/502632/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/401503/35864.

Answer (score 3):

The standard style offered by `bilatex` for annotated bibliography is `reading`, which can be set with `bibstyle` for the purpose:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[bibstyle=reading]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@misc{kyber,
    author       = {Leon Botros and Matthias J. Kannwischer and Peter Schwabe},
    title        = {Memory-Efficient High-Speed Implementation of Kyber on Cortex-M4},
    howpublished = {Cryptology ePrint Archive, Report 2019/489},
    year         = {2019},
    note         = {\url{https://ia.cr/2019/489}},
    annotation   = {Crystals-Kyber PQC spec (one of the NIST PQC finalists).}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]